# How to determine the form of a 3rd rank tensor property for crystal 4/mmm symmetry

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

All of the examples I see show how to determine the form of $Q_{ij}$ in say $M_i = Q_{ij}E_j$ to try to understand the magnetoelastic properties of a crystal.

But what if we want to determine the form of $Q_{ijk}$ in say $ε_{ij} = Q_{kij}H_k$ with 4/mmm symmetry to try to understand the converse piezomagnetic effect?

Comment: What are the symmetry properties of $\epsilon_{ij}$?

Comment: For this example I wanted to consider a crystal of 4/mmm symmetry. 

I think I am starting to understand that the transformation will have 3 different corresponding matrix operations for a 3rd order tensor  that depend on the type of symmetry (whereas for a 2nd order would have 2).